# AS400 Date in Serial Format

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

Does anyone know how to get the current date and time into a yyyymmddhhmmss format from an old AS400 (v5r2)?  I have tried using the sysibm.sysdumm1 current timestamp function but I am unable to remove the system formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way that ought to work in V5R2:

```
select                             
  digits(decimal(                  
    year(current_timestamp) * 10000 +
    month(current_timestamp) * 100 + 
    day(current_timestamp), 8, 0)) ||
  digits(decimal(                  
    hour(current_timestamp) * 10000 +
    minute(current_timestamp) * 100 +
    second(current_timestamp), 6, 0))
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way:

```
select                                                         
  replace(
    replace(                                               
      substr(cast(current_timestamp as varchar(26)), 1, 19),
    '-', ''),  
  '.', '')                                                     
from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: Its a good try but the replace function was introduced in V5R3.  We are on V5R2 - also known as the bane of my existence

Comment: @SteveSalowitz:  See my other answer for another option.